# trying to do a t-test to see whether the average response time across complaint types is similar or not

Tags: python, pandas

```
set1 = df[(df['Complaint Type'] == 'Blocked Driveway')]
set1.reset_index(inplace = True)

set2 = df[(df[Çomplaint Type'] == 'Drinking')]
set2.reset_index(inplace = True)

ttest_ind(set1['Request_Closing_Time'], set2['Request_Closing_Time'])
```

when I run the ttest, I get an error.

```
TypeError: unfunc multiply cannot use operands with types dtype('<m8[ns]) and dtype('<m8[ns])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dtype('<M8\[ns\]') Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831647/dtypem8ns-error)

Answer (score 0):

Line starting with set2 is missing a single quote.

```
set2 = df[(df[‘Çomplaint Type'] == 'Drinking')]
```

Comment: The quote I added should be the same as the others, not on my keyboard.